# Removing newline characters from copy and pasting images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a an html/javascript application as a project where I essentially am creating a markup language and converting the text to pictures. One thing I am doing for this is making it possible to copy and paste the string of pictures into the text area and get the markup version so that I can save it in text format.

I accomplish this by setting the `alt` attribute of my html images to what I want to be copied. Something I'm having trouble with is that when I set it up so that it prints the images "down" instead of to the right, accomplished by creating a sequence of `<div><img alt="words" src="picture"></img></div>` it interprets it as having newline characters between each individual pictures `alt` when I copy and paste.

I've tried adding a backspace character but that obviously failed, does anybody have a solution for getting rid of these newline characters?

Here's a picture of the output and what you get when you copy and paste to help make it more clear

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try set the `img` to `display: block`

Comment: How about adding style `display: inline-block` to the `div` tags? for more info, see **The Easy Way** on [this page](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)

Comment: I want to make the text not have newline characters in it, not have the images be on the same line. `display: inline-block` puts the images on the same line. `display: block` does not get rid of the newline character for me

Answer (score 1):

```
var pasteArea = document.getElementById('pasteArea');

pasteArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
  var value = pasteArea.value;
  var spaceRemoved = value.replace(/\n/g, '');

  if (value !== spaceRemoved) {
    pasteArea.value = spaceRemoved;
  }
});
```

Comment: This way the enters or newline characters i.e. \n will be removed on pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event to your textarea that removes any whitespace (or just newlines if that's preferable) when the value changes:

```js
var pasteArea = document.getElementById('pasteArea');

pasteArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
  var value = pasteArea.value;
  var spaceRemoved = value.replace(/\s/g, '');

  if (value !== spaceRemoved) {
    pasteArea.value = spaceRemoved;
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 10em;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="pasteArea"></textarea>
```